# Is it possible to combine textures in Maya into some sort of atlas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, maya, texture-atlas

I'm starting to use Maya to do some bone animations of a 2D character, which is composed of several different parts (legs, body, head, weapon, etc.). I have each part in a separate .PNG image file. Right now I have a polygon for each part, with its own material and texture:

[image]

I was wondering if there's a way to automatically combine the textures into an atlas, make all the polygons use the same material with the atlas, and correct their UV maps so they still point to the right part of the atlas. Right now, I can do it manually in reverse: I can make the atlas outside Maya with other tools, then use the atlas on a material and manually correct the UV maps of each polygon. But it's a very long process and if I need to change a texture, I have to do it all over again. So I was wondering if there's a way to automate it.

The reason why I'm trying to do this is to save draw calls in Unity. From what I understand, Unity can batch objects as long as they share the same material. So instead of having a draw call for each polygon in the character, I'd like to have a single draw call for the whole character. I'm pretty new to Maya, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very, very broad question, have you attempted anything? Can you show any current workings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the atlassing in Maya, you can do it by duplicating your mesh and using the Transfer Maps tool to bake all of the different meshes onto the duplicate as a single model. The steps would be:

1) Duplicate the mesh

2) Use UV layout to make sure that the duplicated mesh has no overlapping UVs (or only has them where appropriate, like mirrored pieces.

3) Use the **Transfer Maps...** tool to project the original mesh onto the new one, using the "Use topology" option to ensure that the projection is clean.

The end result should be that the new model has the same geometry and appearance as the original, but with all of it's textures combined onto a single sheet attached to a single material.

The limitation of this method is that some kinds of mesh (particularly meshes that self-intersect) may not project properly, leaving you to manually touch up the atlassed texture.   As with any atlassing solution you will probably see some softening in the textures, since the atlas texture is not a pixel for pixel copy but rather a a projection, and thus a resampling.

You may find it more flexible to reprocess the character in Unity with a script or assetPostprocessor.   Unity has a native texture atlassing function, documented [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.PackTextures.html).   Unity comes with a script for combining static meshes, but you'd need to implement your own; theres'a an example on the unity wiki that probably does what you want : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SkinnedMeshCombiner (Caveat: we do something similar to this at work, but I can't share it; I have not used the one in this link).  FWIW Unity's native atlassing works only in rectangles, so it's not as memory efficient as something you could do for yourself.